# Refrence of Quranic verse" muslim slave better than non muslim slave "

Tags: quran, quran-translation, uloom-al-quran, reading-quran, quranic-events

What is the refrence of Quranic verse that approximately means:

A Muslim slave is better than non muslim slave and female muslim slave is better than non muslim female slave because muslims call towards Allah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe. **And a
>   believing slave woman is better than a polytheist, even though she
>   might please you**. And do not marry polytheistic men [to your women]
>   until they believe. **And a believing slave is better than a polytheist,
>   even though he might please you**. Those invite [you] to the Fire, but
>   Allah invites to Paradise and to forgiveness, by His permission. And
>   He makes clear His verses to the people that perhaps they may
>   remember.

Al-Baqarah 221